# Load .war on startup

Tags: linux, java, linux-mint, bash-scripting

Just installed Linux Mint 18 on my spare laptop, and i'm very newbie on linux yet.

I want to make [Gitbucket](https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket) to autostart when i turn on my laptop, but even after reading questions like [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root) and following the init.d answer i cant get this to work.

Just a side note: seems like i need to call java -jar with sudo to make the server work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to make it work without autostart? You should focus on it first and then have it auto-started.

Comment: Yes, the applet will work if i use `java -jar gitbucket.war`, i just cant figure how to make it start automatically